# Replicit? Or a word that sounds like it?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I've looked up "replicit" and it's not a word, or so I can tell. But I could swear that there's a word that sounds like "rep licit" which means "full of" or "abundant." "Rimplicit"? Nope. Does anyone know what the word might be?

Comment: I thought the same about replicit, as an actual word...meaning abundant. If not, it should be a word. It just sounds right. Re- meaning again or over, and licit meaning lawful or to make legal or make tangible. Resplendent meaning rich, lush, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [*replete*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/replete), which fits with the definition you give. For example, one could say that a speech was *replete* with sentimentality.

Comment: Aha! "Replete" is exactly the word I'm looking for!

Answer (score -1):

I think you're thinking of requisite. I do transcription and I have a dictator that every time she says the word it sounds like replicit. I know this was from years ago, but just in case anybody else has trouble with this word, there it is.

Comment: "Requisite" does not mean "full of" or "abundant."

Comment: Similarly, **resplendent** means impressive, rich and glorious.